# Target multiple variables for a function within a custom function

Tags: r, function, chi-squared, custom-function

I would like to build a function which runs a chi square test if `calc=TRUE`. The problem appears to be targeting the variables used within the `wtd.chi.sq` function.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
library(weights); library(sjstats)    
testfunction <- function(dta, x, y, calc=TRUE, annotate=note){
  if(isTRUE(calc)){
    testresult<-wtd.chi.sq(dta[[x]], dta[[y]])
    return(testresult["p.value"])
  }
  else {
    annotate <- paste0(note, "... and no calc necessary")
  }
  return(annotate)
}

testfunction(dta=df, x=f1, y=s12x, calc=TRUE, annotate=note)
```

> Error in tbl_subset2(x, j = i, j_arg = substitute(i)) :
> object 'f1' not found

Comment: Put quotes around your column names. `testfunction(dta=df, x='f1', y='s12x', calc=TRUE, annotate=note)`.

Comment: What an easy solution :) Thank you very much for your help!